# Gentoo Linux -> Ubuntu: Can I Preserve My LVM/RAID Devices, Or Do I Need To Reformat?

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, lvm2

I've got a Gentoo box that I'm interested in switching over to an Ubuntu box.

I currently have the partitions laid out using a mixture of RAID (mdadm) and LVM2, as specified in this document [1].

Ideally I'd like to just wipe out the non /home partition, as it's got data I'd like to keep.

Is it possible to reuse the current setup, or do I need to restart?  vgdisplay, vgchange -a y, etc don't yield any results from the Ubuntu LiveCD, and I'm wary to run any commands that might wipe my data.

Your help would be appreciated.

[1] http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/gentoo-x86+raid+lvm2-quickinstall.xml

Answer (score 0):

Run `pvscan`, `vgscan`, and `lvscan` first, to make sure that the LVM structures are visible. If they aren't then you're best off backing up `/home` and recreating them from scratch.